# SEO - Media File Name Updating

Tags: images, seo

I've been asked to rename my images to better suit what they represent via keywords, for the purpose of SEO.

However, I've noticed that modifying the media images name within WordPress doesn't in turn modify the actual stored image names generated by WordPress, which are used within the HTML.

For example, I have a media jpg image titled "football". I need to rename this to "football-large-spotted". When I do this via the "football" media page, it doesn't change any jpg references on my page "about-footballs", which could be "football-320x320.jpg" when it should now be "football-large-spotted-320x320.jpg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would most likely need to use an plugin like `Media File Renamer` for that or change the image name before the upload.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, and the free version does it all. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck.